# I have the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXmQk.png)

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined (jquery.min.js:2)
at w.fn.init.val (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.error (Default.aspx:380)
at u (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
at k (jquery.min.js:2)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Hello, that's my error. I search on the web but other solved questions doesn't have the same code as me.

My code :

```
$(".selectProjectElement").change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/affectProject",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: "{ id:" + $(this).parent().parent().attr("data-id") + ", elementCode:'" + $(this).val() + "', userID:'" + $("#hidden_userID").val() + "' }",
                success: function () {
                    alert("reussi");
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert("F" + $(this).val() + "F");
                    //alert("Une erreur est survenue.");
                    window.location.pathname = window.location.pathname;
                }
            });
        });
```

I don't know why I have this error and don't find a solution. Have you an idea ? Thank's in advance.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as text ([using code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format »» code/errors/data as an image » nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Hello @Dwhitz , ok I post the error in text format.

Comment: I don't use toLowerCase() personnally . It's because I don't understand why I have this error.

Comment: Only thing I can suggest is you use a non minified version of jQuery so you can set a break point where the error is and see what it is looking for that is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You data line is wrong.

It either needs to be:

```
data: '{ "id": "' + $(this).parent().parent().attr("data-id") + '", "elementCode":"' + $(this).val() + '", "userID": "' + $("#hidden_userID").val() + '"}',
```

or:

```
data: { "id": $(this).parent().parent().attr("data-id"), "elementCode": $(this).val(), "userID": $("#hidden_userID").val()},
```

Personally I would do it with a variable outside

```
$(".selectProjectElement").change(function () {
  var data = { 
    id: $(this).parent().parent().attr("data-id"),
    elementCode: $(this).val(),
    userID: $("#hidden_userID").val()
  }
  $.ajax({
    ...
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    ...
  });
});
```

Comment: I test the two code and it doesn't work :(
The code go into the error function

Comment: Ok, after your edit, I have change my code for transform data into variable. And now it's works ! I don't understand why, but thank's ! I will take a closer look to understand why.

Comment: The way you built the JSON was wrong. It was not valid JSON format.